# Terra does not handler correctly multicategorical rasters

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

I'm currently using terra to manipulate raster. One of them is categorical with bedrock type.

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4346, 5235, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -10.62514, 32.99986, 34.99986, 71.21653  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : lithology.tif 
categories  : xx 
name        : xx 
min value   : sc 
max value   : ig
```

[image]

but when I try to plot it, I get:

```
plot(x)
#[plot] unknown categories in raster values
```

I think it might be the symptome of something that isn't working correctly. Because after, i have troubles with multiple models that use this raster.

Here are the details of my R session and of my terra version :

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3;  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Paris
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.7-71 sf_1.0-15    abind_1.4-5 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.5        cli_3.6.2          rlang_1.1.3        DBI_1.2.1          processx_3.8.3    
 [6] KernSmooth_2.23-22 generics_0.1.3     glue_1.7.0         e1071_1.7-14       pkgbuild_1.4.3    
[11] ps_1.7.6           fansi_1.0.6        grid_4.3.2         tibble_3.2.1       classInt_0.4-10   
[16] lifecycle_1.0.4    compiler_4.3.2     dplyr_1.1.4        codetools_0.2-19   pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[21] Rcpp_1.0.12        rstudioapi_0.15.0  R6_2.5.1           tidyselect_1.2.0   utf8_1.2.4        
[26] class_7.3-22       parallel_4.3.2     pillar_1.9.0       curl_5.2.0         callr_3.7.3       
[31] magrittr_2.0.3     tools_4.3.2        proxy_0.4-27       units_0.8-5        remotes_2.4.2.1   
[36] desc_1.4.3     

terra::gdal(lib="")
    gdal     proj     geos 
 "3.4.3"  "8.2.0" "3.10.2"
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

A categorical raster stores integer values (keys) such as 1, 2, 3 and a table that matches these keys to labels such as "sc", "ss". The message (presumably it is a warning) tells you that there are values in the raster that do not appear in the table. So these values cannot be interpreted (cannot be added to the legend). You could fix this by adding this/these keys to the categories (see `?terra::levels`).

Here is a *minimal, self-contained reproducible example* of what I think you are seeing.

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=c(1,3), cover=c("forest", "water"))
plot(r)
#Warning message:
#[plot] unknown categories in raster values
```

This is because there is no label for cell value "2".

```
levels(r)[[1]]
#  id  cover
#1  1 forest
#2  3  water
```

But as you can see above, "terra" handles that. I could show how to add that missing key, and that would probably fix things for you, but I cannot be sure. You say that you have "troubles", but you are not saying what they are; so I would like to know what these troubles are to understand if I can fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However, it doesnt seems to fix the problem. 
When i run terra::levels() command on my raster, the same number and names of categories appears in my console and in my figure. 
`   Value xx
1      1 sc
2      2 ss
3      3 sm
4      4 vi
5      5 su
6      6 mt
7      7 pb
8      8 pa
9      9 vb
10    10 va
11    11 pi
12    12 wb
13    13 py
14    14 ev
15    15 nd
16    16 ig`

Comment: I did not say this would fix the problem. I suggest to have a look at the manual for `levels` and the other methods described there.  Instead of adding this type of output to the comments please edit and improve your question.